# Getting Error while creating conversation type channel in Amity Cloud sdk

Tags: android, kotlin, chat

AmityChatClient.newChannelRepository()
.createChannel(displayName = name)
.conversation(id)
.build()
.create()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.doOnSuccess { onChatCreateSuccess.invoke(it.getChannelId()) }
.doOnError { onChatCreateFailed.invoke(it.toString()) }
.ignoreElement()

I have logged In but every time I run the code getting error

com.amity.socialcloud.sdk.model.core.error.AmityException: Please login to use SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is Eliza from Amity. It looks like you haven't called the initialization on the app level.

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    AmityCoreClient.setup(
        apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY",
        endpoint = AmityEndpoint.EU // or whichever server you selected on the portal
    )
}
```

}

If that's not the case, are you listening to any changes happening in the session as shown below?

```
AmityCoreClient.observeSessionState().asFlow()
```

Any calls to the repositories should only happen within an active session.